# google result only shows canceled domain

Tags: domains, google-search, multiple-domains, blogger

I created a blog with blogger. Then I took .tk domain for my blog. However later I bought .com domain. 
Then I canceled my .tk domain.
now google search shows .tk results. But ger error once click that results. Can't find .com doman results. what should I do.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Google webmaster tools to notify Google about the change of address:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en

Register your site with WMT (if you haven't already):
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179

and start the process, then wait for a few days for results to show up. I would also use the submit to index feature to speed things up a bit:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1352276?hl=en